# When to write a jQuery plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, jquery-plugins, architecture

It's not a typo: I ask **when** and not how to write a jQuery plugin. :-)

At the moment, I write a jQuery plugin for almost every module of my project. It works fine, but sounds wrong, because actually it has nothing to do with jQuery and is used just once.

In my opinion, a plugin has to be independent from the project itself or used more than once within the project. So, I wonder if my architecture is generally wrong and I'm excited about the upcoming answers.

My architecture right now, shown on a simple Blog example:

**Backend**:

- BlogController.cls.php -  *handles the user actions (e.q. show, comment, find)*
- BlogModel.cls.php - *handles the data actions (e.q. getters, setters, save, delete)*

**Frontend**:

*path: /blog/index/*

- index.htm - *index template for the HTML*
- index.js - *JavaScript*

*path: /blog/post/123/*

- post.htm - *HTML for the post page*
- post.js - *JavaScript*

---

**Example goal**:

I'd like to overwrite the date and time of each blogpost with a cool message like *"added 2 hours ago"* instead of *"added on MM/DD/YYYY HH:ii"*.

So, I wrote the plugin BlogIndex for this page. The plugin itselfs uses another plugin which transforms the timestamp to the String. Here's how I use the plugin BlogIndex:

```
# index.htm
<div id="blog-index">     
    <ul>
        <li>
            <h2>Post Headline</h2>
            <p class="datetime" data-timestamp="1234567890">June, 19th 2013 12:30</p>
        </li>
        <!-- more posts -->
    </ul>
</div>

# index.js
$("#blog-index").BlogIndex({
    liveDateTimePosted: true,       // overwrites "mm/dd/yyyy hh:ii" to "2 hours ago"
    liveDateTimePostedInterval: 500 // refresh every 500 ms
});
```

For the post.htm I would write the plugin BlogPost and so on. I hope, I could explain what I'm doing and why I don't feel happy this way.

What would you change? How would you organise and write your JavaScript in a OOP and modular way? I'm open-minded for every solution!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: _"a plugin has to be independent from the project itself"_ - Not necessarily. If you have some piece of functionality used repeatedly by a single project a plugin still makes sense. If it's used once but you think it might later come in handy elsewhere a plugin still makes sense. If it's used once and clearly won't ever be useful elsewhere then a plugin is overkill.

Comment: By all accounts the use of a plugin makes specfic code/functionality portable and re-usable. If you need to re-use this code a lot or need it to be portable then why not write it as a plugin. In your case portability might not be a factor because you are using it just for this project, but if you need this code to be easily re-usable then a plugin makes sense.

Comment: @MarkWalters: In most cases it's not about re-usability but about having everything in a module or "box" and not written down in a procedurale, messy way. For me, in some cases, it seems to be overkill and I'd like to be corrected before I continue in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

"In my opinion, a plugin has to be independent from the project itself or used more than once within the project." This is it, you've answered your own question, I think.

Comment: Have you tried require.js? It basically allows you to load modules written in the AMD standard/format. Modules can specify dependency modules and so on. Another good (but more complex) alternative is wire.js, which also loads AMD modules. I hope this is helpful.